# How to convert lines to polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile with linestring  type which are the roads and I want to be able to use this in PowerBI but  it doesn't support linestring types. So I want to covert each of the lines into polygons. Polygons that are just rectangles of each of the lines as I still want to represent roads.

Is there a way I can do this in QGIS?

Comment: Did you try to use (buffer)?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer tool:

[image].

If you are using older version of QGIS and need "flat" caps, use grass tool v.buffer which allows creation of flat or round caps.